# Android: Metadata extractor extract unknow tag

Tags: android, metadata

I use [Metadata extractor lib](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) to get data from tif and jpg files.

With jpg format I get almost all meta data but with tif image I get only 2/6 directory (no GPS data).
There is also a special tag value that I would like to get, but can't neither with jpg than tif format: "field of view" = 65.5°

I think field of view tag is a constructor specific tag, so it's not recognize by the library.

Do you know any way to get this information?
Should I modify the library or use another way to extract meta data?
Any help would be great, thanks!

Here is a sample image: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kwhopper said on the GitHub issue tracker, there is no *field of view* tag. This value is calculated from other tag(s), most likely focal length.